# How to cast Observable's Value to Protocol Type

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I am trying to create a NetworkLayer where the requests will return Observable objects.

My idea is to abstract the models with a Protocol/Interface, so the app only knows about the data itself, something like this:

```
public protocol User {

    var id: String? { get }
    var type: String?  { get }
    var firstName: String?  { get }
    var lastName: String? { get }
}
struct UserDTO: User, Codable {

    var id: String?
    var type: String?
    var firstName: String?
    var lastName: String?

    var username: String?
    var address: String?
    ...
}
```

The problem occurred when I try to "cast" the Model to the Interface.

```
class Repository{

    ...
    func getUser(userId: String) -> Observable<User> {

        return networkManager.getUser(userId: userId)
    }
}

class NewtworkManager{

      ...
      func getUser(userId: String) -> Observable<UserDTO> {
        ...
      }
}
```

Due to that I receive this error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type Observable< UserDTO > to return type Observable< User >
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this? Do I need to map the observable before returning it from the Repository class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift generics are invariant (except Swift standard library generics), so you should use map operator:

```
func getUser(userId: String) -> Observable<User> {

    return managerManager.getUser(userId: userId).map { $0 as User }
}
```